# Extreme points of a two-dimensional convex body in terms of its surface area measure

Tags: measure-theory, convex-geometry

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a nonempty compact convex set.
For any $t \in S^1$, define the unit vector $u_t = (\cos t, \sin t)$ making an angle of $t$, and let $l_K(t)$ be the tangent line of $K$ making a normal vector of $u_t$ in the opposite direction of $K$.
For any $t \in S^1$, define the followings.
$$v_K^+(t) = \lim_{t' \to t^+} l_K(t') \cap l_K(t) \qquad v_K^-(t) = \lim_{t' \to t^-} l_K(t') \cap l_K(t)$$
Let $\sigma_K$ be the surface area measure of $K$ on $S^1$ (say, defined like [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387211/the-surface-area-measure-in-terms-of-support-functions)). I believe I proved the followings:

- The points $v_K^+(t)$ and $v_K^-(t)$ are all the extreme points of $K$.
- The point $v_K^+(t)$ is right-continuous with respect to $t \in S^1$.
- The Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $dv_K^+$ of right-continuous $v_K^+ : S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ satisfies $dv_K^+(dt) = w_t \sigma_K(dt)$, where $w_t = (-\sin t, \cos t)$.
- Let $t_1, t_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $t_2 \in (t_1, t_1 + 2 \pi]$. The arc from $v_K^+(t_1)$ to $v_K^+(t_2)$ on the boundary of $K$ in the counterclockwise direction is rectifiable and its length is $\sigma_K((t_1, t_2])$.

The third item essentially tells you that the surface area measure of $K$ comes from the differentiation of the vertex $dv_K^+(t)$ with respect to $t$. If we integrate the differential formula $dv_K^+(dt) = \sigma_K(dt) w_t$ over the whole $S^1$, then we retrieve one side of the [Gauss-Minkowski theorem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.5408.pdf) that $\int_{t \in S^1} w_t \sigma_K(dt) = 0$.

I feel that all the properties are rather elementary and worth being mentioned in some existing literature, so I'm seeking for a literature that proves this instead of me having to reinvent the wheel. But so far I can't find a reference that relates $\sigma_K$ to the vertices of two-dimensional $K$ explicitly. Most literature on surface area measure is focused on general $n$-dimensional convex bodies. With this, can anyone direct me to some possible literature? I'd be also happy to hear some simple proofs of the claims above.